# Master Mind Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently working on a school project, where the assignment is to re-create the game "MasterMind" using Arrays and for loops, however, I am having difficulty correctly adding up the number of white pegs, and I get an output like this.

```
4
7
2
1
What is your guess? No spaces
4444
there are 1 reds, and 2 whites
```

As you can see, it incorrectly outputs the wrong amount of white pegs. Any advice and/or solutions to my issue would be much appreciated.

```
public static void MasterMind(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();
        int red = 0, white = 0;
        int ball;
        int userInput;
        int[] ballNum;
        ballNum = new int[4];
        int[] Input;
        Input = new int[4];
        ball = r.nextInt(9999-1000)+1000;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            ballNum[i] = ball%10;
            ball /= 10;
            System.out.println(ballNum[i]);
        }
        for (int d = 0; d < 8; d++){
            System.out.println("What is your guess? No spaces");
            userInput = input.nextInt();
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                Input[i] = userInput % 10;
                userInput /= 10;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                int m = 0;
                int n = 0;
                if(Input[i] == ballNum[i]){
                    red++;
                    Input[i] = 10000;
                }
                m++;
                n++;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                    if(i != j && Input[j] == ballNum[i]){
                        white++;
                        Input[j] = 1000000;
                    }
                }
            }
            white -= red;

            if(white < 0){
                white = 0;
            }
            System.out.println("there are "+red+" reds, and "+white+" whites");
            white = 0;
            red = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain 1) what the correct output should be, and 2) the logic behind how your algorithm is supposed to work?

Comment: For the example I provided, the output should have been 0, and I'm attempting to compare the inputed digits individually to each of the "ball" numbers, and when they matchup, re-assigning the inputed number to another that has no chance of equaling the ball numbers

Comment: so, 4 in first place match with first four in 4444 and others doesn't match so red count = 1 and at the end white = 0 and substracting it to red equals -1 which should be thresholded to 0 am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is with your loop where user Input is converted to array. You are doing in wrong order. Replace that loop with following code.

```
for(int i = 3; i >=0; i--){
    Input[i] = userInput % 10;
        userInput /= 10;
}
```

And another important thing is why are you substracting reds from white ? just remove the line

```
        white -= red;
```

Then your program works fine